# Change css positioning using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-position

This code works perfectly as i expected but the problem is when i refresh the page the t_con stays in absolute which should be fixed and when i resize the window less than 980px it is in absolute like what i need and if i resize again more than 980px it goes fixed.

i need it to stay fixed from start. I dont know why it is in absolute at first.

HTML CODE

```
<div id="t_con">
<div id="t">

</div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
#t_con{
width:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
}
#t{
margin:0px auto 0 auto;
background-color:#976398;
width:980px;
height:30px;
}
```

Javascript CODE

```
window.onresize = function(){
var pos = window.outerWidth < 980 ? 'absolute' : 'fixed';
document.getElementById('t_con').style.position = pos;
}window.onresize=function(){
var header=document.getElementById('t');
var window_width = document.body.offsetWidth;
if(window_width < 980){
header.style.position="absolute";
}else{
header.style.position="fixed";
}
}
```

Can anyone tell what i am doing wrong in here. And i don't want to use jQuery for this.
So pls dont suggest it. The reason i dont like jQuery is it already takes 90kb plus the code we are trying to execute.

Comment: `t_con.innerWidth` what the heck is `t_con`, you named it `header`, and you should probably check the `window`, right ?

Comment: i need to change it??/

Comment: Got the answer guys... I made amistake in the code and it was noted to me by adeneo.

Comment: Then feel free to accept the answer when you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onresize=function(){
var header=document.getElementByID('t_con');
var window_width = document.body.offsetWidth;
if(window_width < 980){
    header.style.position="absolute";
}else{
    header.style.position="fixed";
}
}
```

Comment: can you relook my question pls @adidi

Answer (score 4):

```
window.onresize = function(){
    var pos = window.outerWidth < 980 ? 'absolute' : 'fixed';
    document.getElementById('t_con').style.position = pos;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wULZk/embedded/result/)

Comment: if i resize the window it is not changing to absolute. it stays fixed.

Comment: You had a typo, it's getElementById, with the last d in lowercase.

Comment: oh thank you i am an idiot i made this simple mistake and was about to cry for not working. thank you so much.

Comment: can you relook my question pls @adeneo